# Excel 2016 changes my cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, cell-format

Recently, whenever I enter a number into Excel, it automatically changes the value of that number. For example:

I enter the data 238:
[image]

Excel automatically change it into 23.8:
[image]

For clarification, this occurred after I made some changes in Excel. Last week, I needed to change the character used to separate thousands or decimals in my documents (from the system default 1,000,000 into 1.000.000). I followed the instructions by unchecking the "Use system separators" in the Option>Advanced, and input my own version in.

I have tried resetting the settings, and changing the language and region, but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you may have automatic decimal place insertion on?

Not sure about 2016, but in 2010, it was File > Options , then the Advanced section, and then uncheck "Automatically insert a decimal point"

reference: http://excelribbon.tips.net/T007563_Entered_Values_are_Divided_by_100.html

Comment: Thank you very much, it is indeed the automatic decimal insertion!